# Metadata discovery only supports temp tables when analyzing a single-statement batch - SSIS package error

Tags: sql, ssis, visual-studio-2017, temp-tables

I'm trying to a temp table in a CTE SQL statement. It runs well in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but when I try to use the SQL statements in Visual Studio - SSIS package it only executes one time an then get an error message. I have tried to set the Execute SQL Task to FALSE - which includes the statement that creates to temp table, and the Data Flow Task's DelayValidation to TRUE. Not sure how else to do solve the errors I'm getting. Any suggestions?

[Seque Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsC1Z.png)

[Data Flow Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JINUX.png)

### This is the first SQL statement used in the Execute SQL Task

```
IF
(
OBJECT_ID('[tempdb].[dbo].[##StrategyMapInventory_2023]')
IS NOT NULL
)

DROP TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[##StrategyMapInventory_2023]

GO
;

CREATE TABLE ##StrategyMapInventory_2023 (
    PersonID VARCHAR(80)
    , CaseID VARCHAR(80)
    , Date date
    , ProgramGroup VARCHAR (1300)
    , ProgramName VARCHAR(1300)
    , MetricName VARCHAR (50)
    , Classification VARCHAR (10)
    , Timeframe  VARCHAR (50)
    , WeekID int
        , WeekStart DATE
        , WeekEnd DATE
        );
INSERT INTO ##StrategyMapInventory_2023
SELECT *
FROM bi.StrategyMapInventory_2023
```

### Second SQL statement used in the Data Flow Task > OLE DB Source

```
DECLARE @ReportGroup VARCHAR(250) = 'Strategy Map 2023'
    , @StartDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE, '1/1/2023')
        , @EndDate DATE = CASE WHEN GETDATE() < '1/1/2024' THEN GETDATE() ELSE '12/31/2023' END

--Get detail from function--------------------------------

    ;WITH ImportDetail AS
    (   SELECT ReportGroup = @ReportGroup
            , ReportSubGroup = ProgramGroup
        , MetricName
            , WeekID
        , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProgramGroup, MetricName, PersonID ORDER BY Date)
        , PersonID
        , Date
        FROM ##StrategyMapInventory_2023
        WHERE [Date] >= @StartDate
        GROUP BY ProgramGroup
                , MetricName
                , WeekID
        , PersonID
        , Date)
 
    , Detail AS
     (   SELECT ReportGroup
                , ReportSubGroup
            , MetricName
            , WeekID
            , Amount = COUNT(DISTINCT(PersonID))
        FROM ImportDetail
        WHERE RowNumber = 1
        GROUP BY ReportGroup
            , ReportSubGroup
            , MetricName
            , WeekID
            )

--Get detail from function--------------------------------

--Get unique ReportGroups---------------------------------
    , AllReportGroups AS
    (   SELECT DISTINCT ReportGroup
        FROM Detail )
--Get unique ReportGroups---------------------------------

 
--Get unique ReportSubGroups---------------------------------
    , AllReportSubGroups AS
    (   SELECT DISTINCT ReportSubGroup
        FROM Detail )
--Get unique ReportSubGroups---------------------------------


--Get unique category values------------------------------
    , Categories AS
    (   SELECT DISTINCT MetricName
        FROM ##StrategyMapInventory_2023 )
--Get unique category values------------------------------
 

--Get all weeks and categories----------------------------
    , AllWeeksAndCategories AS
    (   SELECT w.ID
            , c.MetricName
        FROM reference.WeekStartEnd w
            CROSS JOIN Categories c
        WHERE w.WeekEnd > @StartDate
        AND w.WeekEnd < DATEADD(DAY,7,GETDATE()) --include data from current week, but limit inclusion of future weeks' data==============
     )
--Get all weeks and categories----------------------------

--Get all weeks, categories, ReportGroups, and ReportSubGroups--------------
    , AllWeeksCategoriesAndReportGroups AS
    (   SELECT r.ReportGroup
        , rs.ReportSubGroup
            , w.ID
            , c.MetricName
        FROM reference.WeekStartEnd w
            CROSS JOIN Categories c
            CROSS JOIN AllReportGroups r
            CROSS JOIN AllReportSubGroups rs
        WHERE w.WeekEnd > @StartDate
        AND w.WeekEnd < DATEADD(DAY,7,GETDATE()) --include data from current week, but limit inclusion of future weeks' data==============
    )

--Get all weeks, categories, ReportGroups, and ReportSubGroups--------------


--Raw results---------------------------------------------
    , ResultsByProgram AS
    (   SELECT ReportGroup = awc.ReportGroup
            , ReportSubGroup = awc.ReportSubGroup
            , MetricName = COALESCE(d.MetricName, awc.MetricName)
            , WeekID = awc.ID
            , Amount = COALESCE(d.Amount, 0)
        FROM AllWeeksCategoriesAndReportGroups awc
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Detail d
                ON awc.ReportGroup = d.ReportGroup
                AND awc.ReportSubGroup = d.ReportSubGroup
                AND awc.MetricName = d.MetricName
                AND awc.ID = d.WeekID )
--Raw results---------------------------------------------
 
--All Programs--------------------------------------------
    , AllProgramsDetail AS
    (   SELECT PersonID
            , Date
            , Num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID, MetricName ORDER BY PersonID, MetricName, Date)
            , ReportGroup = @ReportGroup
            , ReportSubGroup = 'All'
            , MetricName
            , WeekID
        FROM ##StrategyMapInventory_2023
        WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate )
 
    , AllProgramsSource AS
    (   SELECT ReportGroup
        , ReportSubGroup
            , MetricName
            , WeekID
            , Amount = COUNT(*)
        FROM AllProgramsDetail
        WHERE Num = 1
        GROUP BY ReportGroup
        , ReportSubGroup
            , MetricName
                , WeekID )
--All Programs--------------------------------------------


--Return results------------------------------------------------
    SELECT * FROM ResultsByProgram
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM AllProgramsSource
    ORDER BY ReportGroup
        , ReportSubGroup
        , MetricName
        , WeekID
--Return results------------------------------------------------
```

I tried changing the DelayValidation from False to True on the result table that depends on the temp table based on what I read on the following articles.

[How to create and use Temp tables in SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/)

[How to use Temp tables in an SSIS package](https://tidbytez.com/2015/12/29/tutorial-how-to-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/)

Comment: We ended up not using temp tables and just shorten the query for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set `RetainSameConnection = true` in your connection manager properties as detailed in the first article (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/).

Comment: Thank you! I did and still gave me the same error.

Comment: @KristyLopez Set `DelayValidation=true` on the  _Strategy Map Eradicate 2023_ data flow task in your sequence container and, if you have previously disabled it, keep the _Create Temp Table_ task enabled. I replicated the error and this resolved it.